# Bootstrap issues - card row not resizing when margins added

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm wondering if anyone can help.

I have my bootstrap cards set up to have 3 in a row on a larger screen then to resizes for smaller devices. The issue is that the cards appear as a grid, I want to add a small margin to the right of the cards to make them appear separate and not like a table.

Every time I add a margin-right it pushes the cards out of alignment and onto the next rows. How can I add the margin-right and still keep the cards on the same rows?

This is my code so far:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Account Dashboard</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style>

        .card-container {
            border: 1px solid rgba(191, 191, 191, 1);
            border-radius: 0px;
            padding-right: 0px;
            padding-left: 0px;
            /*margin: 10px;*/

        }

        .row{
            margin-bottom:10px;
        }

        .card-body {
            padding: 10px;
        }

        .ul-align {
            text-align: left;
            padding-left: 105px;
            margin-bottom: 0px !important;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: normal;
            color: #787878;
        }

        .account-icon {
            padding: 10px 10px 10px 0;
            margin-right: 10px;
            float: left;
            display: flex;
        }

        @media (max-width: 980px) and (min-width: 640px) {
            .ul-align {
                text-align: left;
                padding-left: 20px;
                margin-bottom: 0px !important;
            }

            .account-icon {
                display: none;
            }
        }

        .account-title {
            font-size: 24px;
            font-weight: 400px;
            color: #787878;
            padding-bottom:20px;
        }

        .card-title {
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: 400px;
            color: #787878;
        }

    </style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <h1 class="account-title">My Account</h1>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="card-container bg-light col-3 col-md-4 col-12 col-6 mr-1">
            <div class="card-body ">
                <img class="account-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/70" alt="Card image cap">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card Title</h4>
                <ul class="ul-align">
                    <li>Descriptive text</li>
                    <li>Descriptive text</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-container bg-light col-3 col-md-4 col-12 col-6">
            <div class="card-body ">
                <img class="account-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/70" alt="Card image cap">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card Title</h4>
                <ul class="ul-align">
                    <li>Descriptive text</li>
                    <li>Descriptive text</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-container bg-light col-3 col-md-4 col-12 col-6">
            <div class="card-body ">
                <img class="account-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/70" alt="Card image cap">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card Title</h4>
                <ul class="ul-align">
                    <li>Descriptive text</li>
                    <li>Descriptive text</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="card-container bg-light col-3 col-md-4 col-12 col-6">
            <div class="card-body ">
                <img class="account-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/70" alt="Card image cap">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card Title</h4>
                <ul class="ul-align">
                    <li>Descriptive text</li>
                    <li>Descriptive text</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-container bg-light col-3 col-md-4 col-12 col-6">
            <div class="card-body ">
                <img class="account-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/70" alt="Card image cap">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card Title</h4>
                <ul class="ul-align">
                    <li>Descriptive text</li>
                    <li>Descriptive text</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-container bg-light col-3 col-md-4 col-12 col-6">
            <div class="card-body ">
                <img class="account-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/70" alt="Card image cap">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card Title</h4>
                <ul class="ul-align">
                    <li>Descriptive text</li>
                    <li>Descriptive text</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey do you think it is possible for you to add a snippet?

Comment: Code is already there @khushi :) Copy and paste

Comment: @SJ0175 : Have provided a complete solution for you. Do vote and accept the answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick in this case is to add a wrapper div around columns and give it a small padding. I used `p-2` utitlity class in the given problem.

**Working Code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Account Dashboard</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style>
      .card-container {
        border: 1px solid rgba(191, 191, 191, 1);
        border-radius: 0px;
        padding-right: 0px;
        padding-left: 0px;
        /*margin: 10px;*/
      }

      .row {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }

      .card-body {
        padding: 10px;
      }

      .ul-align {
        text-align: left;
        padding-left: 105px;
        margin-bottom: 0px !important;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: normal;
        color: #787878;
      }

      .account-icon {
        margin-right: 10px;
        float: left;
        display: flex;
      }

      @media (max-width: 980px) and (min-width: 640px) {
        .ul-align {
          text-align: left;
          padding-left: 20px;
          margin-bottom: 0px !important;
        }

        .account-icon {
          display: none;
        }
      }

      .account-title {
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: 400px;
        color: #787878;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
      }

      .card-title {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 400px;
        color: #787878;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="account-title">My Account</h1>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3 col-md-4 col-12 col-6 p-2">
          <article class="card-container bg-light">
            <div class="card-body">
              <img
                class="account-icon"
                src="https://via.placeholder.com/70"
                alt="Card image cap"
              />
              <h4 class="card-title">Card Title</h4>
              <ul class="ul-align">
                <li>Descriptive text</li>
                <li>Descriptive text</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </article>
        </div>

        <div class="col-3 col-md-4 col-12 col-6 p-2">
          <article class="card-container bg-light">
            <div class="card-body">
              <img
                class="account-icon"
                src="https://via.placeholder.com/70"
                alt="Card image cap"
              />
              <h4 class="card-title">Card Title</h4>
              <ul class="ul-align">
                <li>Descriptive text</li>
                <li>Descriptive text</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </article>
        </div>

        <div class="col-3 col-md-4 col-12 col-6 p-2">
          <article class="card-container bg-light">
            <div class="card-body">
              <img
                class="account-icon"
                src="https://via.placeholder.com/70"
                alt="Card image cap"
              />
              <h4 class="card-title">Card Title</h4>
              <ul class="ul-align">
                <li>Descriptive text</li>
                <li>Descriptive text</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </article>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3 col-md-4 col-12 col-6 p-2">
          <article class="card-container bg-light">
            <div class="card-body">
              <img
                class="account-icon"
                src="https://via.placeholder.com/70"
                alt="Card image cap"
              />
              <h4 class="card-title">Card Title</h4>
              <ul class="ul-align">
                <li>Descriptive text</li>
                <li>Descriptive text</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </article>
        </div>

        <div class="col-3 col-md-4 col-12 col-6 p-2">
          <article class="card-container bg-light">
            <div class="card-body">
              <img
                class="account-icon"
                src="https://via.placeholder.com/70"
                alt="Card image cap"
              />
              <h4 class="card-title">Card Title</h4>
              <ul class="ul-align">
                <li>Descriptive text</li>
                <li>Descriptive text</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </article>
        </div>

        <div class="col-3 col-md-4 col-12 col-6 p-2">
          <article class="card-container bg-light">
            <div class="card-body">
              <img
                class="account-icon"
                src="https://via.placeholder.com/70"
                alt="Card image cap"
              />
              <h4 class="card-title">Card Title</h4>
              <ul class="ul-align">
                <li>Descriptive text</li>
                <li>Descriptive text</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </article>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: u r most welcome. Well this was the trick to be followed in this case.  Personally i would like to do the grid stuff using CSS-grid, this makes things a lot lot easy. Whenever u have time,do learn CSS-Grid. Have a great time. God bless :)